# How to resolve the many-to-many relation keeping the order of ID array in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections `posts` and `tags` on mongoDB.
There is a many-to-many relationship between these collections.
A post can belong to some tags, and a tag can contain some posts.

I am looking for an efficient query method to join `posts` to `tags` keeping the order of `postIds`.

If the data schema is inappropriate, I can change it.

The mongoDB version is 3.6.5

#### Sample data

```
db.posts.insertMany([
  { _id: 'post001', title: 'this is post001' },
  { _id: 'post002', title: 'this is post002' },
  { _id: 'post003', title: 'this is post003' }
])

db.tags.insertMany([
  { _id: 'tag001', postIds: ['post003', 'post001', 'post002'] }
])
```

#### Desired result

```
{
  "_id": "tag001",
  "postIds": [ "post003", "post001", "post002" ],
  "posts": [
    { "_id": "post003", "title": "this is post003" },
    { "_id": "post001", "title": "this is post001" },
    { "_id": "post002", "title": "this is post002" }
  ]
}
```

#### What I tried

I tried a query which use `$lookup`.

```
db.tags.aggregate([
  { $lookup: {
      from: 'posts',
      localField: 'postIds',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'posts'
  }}
])
```

However I got a result which is different from I want.

```
{
  "_id": "tag001",
  "postIds": [ "post003", "post001", "post002" ],
  "posts": [
    { "_id": "post001", "title": "this is post001" },
    { "_id": "post002", "title": "this is post002" },
    { "_id": "post003", "title": "this is post003" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You have typo in there: `posts002` instead of `post002`

Comment: Thank you, I fixed typo.

Comment: Now, the third sub document is missing from your current output. Mind you, none of that solves your problem. ;)

Comment: I don't know reason but post002 is disappeared in my current result. To avoid confuse, I added explain about this. Thank you.

Comment: It's missing because of your typo

Comment: I understand.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MongoDB you would attempt to model your data such that you avoid joins (as in `$lookup`s) alltogether, e.g. by storing the `tags` alongside the `posts`.

```
db.posts.insertMany([
  { _id: 'post001', title: 'this is post001', tags: [ "tag001", "tag002" ] },
  { _id: 'post002', title: 'this is post002', tags: [ "tag001" ] },
  { _id: 'post003', title: 'this is post003', tags: [ "tag002" ] }
])
```

With this structure in place you could get the desired result like this:

```
db.posts.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$tags"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$tags",
        postsIds: {
            $push: "$_id"
        },
        posts: {
            $push: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}])
```

In this case, I would doubt that you even need the `postIds` field in the result as it would be contained in the `posts` array anyway.

Comment: This is definitely the approach to take. Remember to index the `tags` field, so you can do efficient lookups like `db.posts.find({tags: 'tag002'})`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map) and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter) to re-order elements in the `posts` array in a projection stage:

```
db.tags.aggregate([
    { $lookup: {
          from: 'posts',
          localField: 'postIds',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'posts'
    } },
    { $project: {
        _id: 1,
        postIds: 1,
        posts: { $map: { 
            input: "$postIds", 
            as: "postId", 
            in: {
                $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { 
                    input: "$posts", 
                    as: "post", 
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$post._id", "$$postId"] } 
                } }, 0 ] 
            } 
        } }
    } }
])
```

The missing posts will be filled with `null` to keep index consistent with `postIds`.